# Evaluate $\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

The following question was asked in JEE 2010.

> Evaluate $\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx$

One method is to open the bracket in the numerator, divide by denominator and then integrate the result.

**Is there any other way?**

I tried $x=\tan\theta$ but couldn't conclude.

I also tried the property $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$ but in vain.

Comment: Yes you can view my video here: https://youtu.be/X5iJfv2in-8

Comment: @EkaveeraGouribhatla thankyou